# Opening password protected files in Stata

Tags: stata, xlsx, password-protection

I am attempting to open a password protected .xlsx file in Stata. I have the password, so opening the file, copying the contents, and pasting them into another file is an option.

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-06/msg01359.html

Another option is to copy the entire file, remove the password protection, and proceed from there, but again this is not ideal.

Is there a way to open a password protected .xlsx file in Stata without using some workaround?

Comment: What are you seeking? An option to an `import` command that lets you spell out a password? I'd take it to be a StataCorp line not to give you code that could compromise your own security. (I've no idea what's possible here.)

Comment: An import command would be nice but not ideal, as that would allow for, as you mentioned, the ability to compromise security. A break in active code and a command prompt within Stata that would close out with a successful password entry would be nice.

Comment: I'd ask StataCorp technical support. I doubt that such a thing would ever be written, but that is pure guesswork.

Comment: Statacorp know what you really want